# useradd does not work

Tags: solaris, useradd

On a server running Solaris 10, the command `useradd` fails to add new users. Running `useradd -m` creates the home directories but all with user id 50011.

Please review the output below:

```
# useradd -s /bin/bash -m testuser
# echo $?
0
# passwd testuser
passwd: User unknown: testuser
Permission denied
# grep -i testuser /etc/passwd
# ls -lh /etc/passwd
-rw-r--r--   1 root     sys          779 Oct  6  2012 /etc/passwd
# ls -lh /etc/shadow
-r--------   1 root     sys          385 Nov 13 13:50 /etc/shadow


# type useradd
useradd is /usr/sbin/useradd
# useradd -s /bin/bash -d /home/testuser -m testuser
# passwd testuser
passwd: User unknown: testuser
Permission denied


# useradd testuser
# passwd testuser
passwd: User unknown: testuser
Permission denied



 # ls -lth /home/ | head -6
 total 36
 drwxr-xr-x   2 50011    other        512 Nov 13 19:37 test3
 drwxr-xr-x   2 50011    other        512 Nov 13 19:36 test2
 drwxr-xr-x   2 50011    other        512 Nov 13 19:27 test1
 drwxr-xr-x   2 50011    other        512 Nov 13 14:56 testuser
 drwxr-xr-x   2 50011    other        512 Nov 13 14:46 test_user



# df -k /home;ls -l@ /usr/sbin/useradd; pkgchk SUNWcsu; grep passwd: /etc/nsswitch.conf
Filesystem            kbytes    used   avail capacity  Mounted on
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s6    20646961  604690 19835802     3%    /home
-r-xr-xr-x   2 root     sys        40252 Jul  6  2011 /usr/sbin/useradd
passwd:     files ldap

# useradd -s /bin/bash -b /export/home -m testuser
UX: useradd: ERROR: invalid syntax.
usage:  useradd [-u uid [-o] | -g group | -G group[[,group]...] |-d dir |
                -s shell | -c comment | -m [-k skel_dir] | -f inactive |
                -e expire | -A authorization [, authorization ...] |
                -P profile [, profile ...] | -R role [, role ...] |
                -K key=value | -p project [, project ...]] login
        useradd -D [-g group | -b base_dir | -f inactive | -e expire
                -A authorization [, authorization ...] |
                -P profile [, profile ...] | -R role [, role ...] |
                -K key=value ... -p project]



# userdel testuser
UX: userdel: ERROR: testuser does not exist.
# truss -t\!memcntl,getuid,door_call,door_info,close,mmap,brk,munmap,lwp_sigmask,sigaction,llseek -f useradd -m -d /tmp/testuser testuser
1064:   execve("/usr/sbin/useradd", 0xFFBFFCC4, 0xFFBFFCDC)  argc = 5
1064:   sysinfo(SI_MACHINE, "sun4v", 257)               = 6
1064:   resolvepath("/usr/lib/ld.so.1", "/lib/ld.so.1", 1023) = 12
1064:   resolvepath("/usr/sbin/useradd", "/usr/sbin/useradd", 1023) = 17
1064:   stat64("/usr/sbin/useradd", 0xFFBFF790)         = 0
1064:   open("/var/ld/ld.config", O_RDONLY)             = 3
1064:   fstat64(3, 0xFFBFF300)                          = 0
1064:   stat64("/lib/libsecdb.so.1", 0xFFBFEEF0)        = 0
1064:   resolvepath("/lib/libsecdb.so.1", "/lib/libsecdb.so.1", 1023) = 18
1064:   open("/lib/libsecdb.so.1", O_RDONLY)            = 3
1064:   stat64("/lib/libproject.so.1", 0xFFBFEEF0)      Err#2 ENOENT
1064:   stat64("/usr/lib/libproject.so.1", 0xFFBFEEF0)  = 0
1064:   resolvepath("/usr/lib/libproject.so.1", "/usr/lib/libproject.so.1", 1023) = 24
1064:   open("/usr/lib/libproject.so.1", O_RDONLY)      = 3
1064:   stat64("/lib/libc.so.1", 0xFFBFEEF0)            = 0
1064:   resolvepath("/lib/libc.so.1", "/lib/libc.so.1", 1023) = 14
1064:   open("/lib/libc.so.1", O_RDONLY)                = 3
1064:   stat64("/lib/libnsl.so.1", 0xFFBFEEF0)          = 0
1064:   resolvepath("/lib/libnsl.so.1", "/lib/libnsl.so.1", 1023) = 16
1064:   open("/lib/libnsl.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
1064:   stat64("/lib/libcmd.so.1", 0xFFBFEEF0)          = 0
1064:   resolvepath("/lib/libcmd.so.1", "/lib/libcmd.so.1", 1023) = 16
1064:   open("/lib/libcmd.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
1064:   stat64("/lib/libproc.so.1", 0xFFBFEEF0)         = 0
1064:   resolvepath("/lib/libproc.so.1", "/lib/libproc.so.1", 1023) = 17
1064:   open("/lib/libproc.so.1", O_RDONLY)             = 3
1064:   stat64("/lib/librtld_db.so.1", 0xFFBFEEF0)      = 0
1064:   resolvepath("/lib/librtld_db.so.1", "/lib/librtld_db.so.1", 1023) = 20
1064:   open("/lib/librtld_db.so.1", O_RDONLY)          = 3
1064:   stat64("/lib/libelf.so.1", 0xFFBFEEF0)          = 0
1064:   resolvepath("/lib/libelf.so.1", "/lib/libelf.so.1", 1023) = 16
1064:   open("/lib/libelf.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
1064:   stat64("/lib/libctf.so.1", 0xFFBFEEF0)          = 0
1064:   resolvepath("/lib/libctf.so.1", "/lib/libctf.so.1", 1023) = 16
1064:   open("/lib/libctf.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
1064:   getcontext(0xFFBFF600)
1064:   getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, 0xFFBFF5E0)             = 0
1064:   getpid()                                        = 1064 [1063]
1064:   setustack(0xFF0B2A88)
1064:   sigfillset(0xFF31B3BC)                          = 0
1064:   stat64("/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libc_psr.so.1", 0xFFBFEA90) = 0
1064:   resolvepath("/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libc_psr.so.1", "/platform/sun4v/lib/libc_psr.so.1", 1023) = 33
1064:   open("/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libc_psr.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
1064:   sysconfig(_CONFIG_PAGESIZE)                     = 8192
1064:   open("/usr/sadm/defadduser", O_RDONLY)          = 3
1064:   fstat64(3, 0xFFBFE768)                          = 0
1064:   fstat64(3, 0xFFBFE610)                          = 0
1064:   ioctl(3, TCGETA, 0xFFBFE6F4)                    Err#25 ENOTTY
1064:   read(3, " #\t D e f a u l t   v a".., 8192)     = 286
1064:   read(3, 0x0002B23C, 8192)                       = 0
1064:   getpid()                                        = 1064 [1063]
1064:   open("/proc/1064/psinfo", O_RDONLY)             = 3
1064:   read(3, "02\0\0\0\0\0\001\0\004 (".., 336)      = 336
1064:   open64("/var/run/name_service_door", O_RDONLY)  = 3
1064:   fcntl(3, F_SETFD, 0x00000001)                   = 0
1064:   stat("/tmp/testuser", 0xFFBFEBB8)               = 0
1064:   schedctl()                                      = 0xFF330000
1064:   fork1()                                         = 1065
1065:   fork1()         (returning as child ...)        = 1064
1065:   getpid()                                        = 1065 [1064]
1065:   lwp_self()                                      = 1
1065:   open("/dev/null", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 1
1065:   open("/dev/null", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 2
1065:   execve("/usr/bin/passmgmt", 0x0002B670, 0x0002C0F4)  argc = 29
1065:   sysinfo(SI_MACHINE, "sun4v", 257)               = 6
1065:   resolvepath("/usr/sbin/passmgmt", "/usr/sbin/passmgmt", 1023) = 18
1065:   stat64("/usr/sbin/passmgmt", 0xFFBFF680)        = 0
1065:   open("/var/ld/ld.config", O_RDONLY)             = 3
1065:   fstat64(3, 0xFFBFF1F0)                          = 0
1065:   stat64("/lib/libsecdb.so.1", 0xFFBFEDE0)        = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libsecdb.so.1", "/lib/libsecdb.so.1", 1023) = 18
1065:   open("/lib/libsecdb.so.1", O_RDONLY)            = 3
1065:   stat64("/lib/passwdutil.so.1", 0xFFBFEDE0)      Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/passwdutil.so.1", 0xFFBFEDE0)  = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/usr/lib/passwdutil.so.1", "/usr/lib/passwdutil.so.1", 1023) = 24
1065:   open("/usr/lib/passwdutil.so.1", O_RDONLY)      = 3
1065:   stat64("/lib/libc.so.1", 0xFFBFEDE0)            = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libc.so.1", "/lib/libc.so.1", 1023) = 14
1065:   open("/lib/libc.so.1", O_RDONLY)                = 3
1065:   stat64("/lib/libnsl.so.1", 0xFFBFEDE0)          = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libnsl.so.1", "/lib/libnsl.so.1", 1023) = 16
1065:   open("/lib/libnsl.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
1065:   stat64("/lib/libcmd.so.1", 0xFFBFEDE0)          = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libcmd.so.1", "/lib/libcmd.so.1", 1023) = 16
1065:   open("/lib/libcmd.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
1065:   getcontext(0xFFBFF4F0)
1065:   getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, 0xFFBFF4D0)             = 0
1065:   getpid()                                        = 1065 [1064]
1065:   setustack(0xFF362A88)
1065:   sigfillset(0xFF31B3BC)                          = 0
1065:   stat64("/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libc_psr.so.1", 0xFFBFE980) = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libc_psr.so.1", "/platform/sun4v/lib/libc_psr.so.1", 1023) = 33
1065:   open("/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libc_psr.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
1065:   time()                                          = 1384439953
1065:   open("/var/run/tzsync", O_RDONLY)               = 3
1065:   open("/usr/share/lib/zoneinfo/US/Eastern", O_RDONLY) = 3
1065:   fstat64(3, 0xFFBFF4A0)                          = 0
1065:   read(3, " T Z i f\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0".., 1267)     = 1267
1065:   creat("/etc/.pwd.lock", 0600)                   = 3
1065:   fcntl(3, F_SETLK, 0xFF3159D0)                   = 0
1065:   getpid()                                        = 1065 [1064]
1065:   stat64("/lib/libsldap.so.1", 0xFFBFE980)        Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/libsldap.so.1", 0xFFBFE980)    = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/usr/lib/libsldap.so.1", "/usr/lib/libsldap.so.1", 1023) = 22
1065:   open("/usr/lib/libsldap.so.1", O_RDONLY)        = 4
1065:   stat64("/lib/libldap.so.5", 0xFFBFE8A0)         Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/libldap.so.5", 0xFFBFE8A0)     = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/usr/lib/libldap.so.5", "/usr/lib/libldap.so.5", 1023) = 21
1065:   open("/usr/lib/libldap.so.5", O_RDONLY)         = 4
1065:   stat64("/lib/libscf.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0)          = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libscf.so.1", "/lib/libscf.so.1", 1023) = 16
1065:   open("/lib/libscf.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 4
1065:   stat64("/lib/libdoor.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0)         = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libdoor.so.1", "/lib/libdoor.so.1", 1023) = 17
1065:   open("/lib/libdoor.so.1", O_RDONLY)             = 4
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/libc.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0)    Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   stat64("/lib/libuutil.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0)        = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libuutil.so.1", "/lib/libuutil.so.1", 1023) = 18
1065:   open("/lib/libuutil.so.1", O_RDONLY)            = 4
1065:   stat64("/lib/libgen.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0)          = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libgen.so.1", "/lib/libgen.so.1", 1023) = 16
1065:   open("/lib/libgen.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 4
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/libsocket.so.1", 0xFFBFE598) Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   stat64("/lib/libsocket.so.1", 0xFFBFE598)       = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libsocket.so.1", "/lib/libsocket.so.1", 1023) = 19
1065:   open("/lib/libsocket.so.1", O_RDONLY)           = 4
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/libnsl.so.1", 0xFFBFE598)  Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   stat64("/lib/libmp.so.2", 0xFFBFE980)           = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libmp.so.2", "/lib/libmp.so.2", 1023) = 15
1065:   open("/lib/libmp.so.2", O_RDONLY)               = 4
1065:   stat64("/lib/libmd.so.1", 0xFFBFE980)           = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libmd.so.1", "/lib/libmd.so.1", 1023) = 15
1065:   open("/lib/libmd.so.1", O_RDONLY)               = 4
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/libsasl.so.1", 0xFFBFE980) Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   stat64("/lib/libsasl.so.1", 0xFFBFE980)         Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/libsasl.so.1", 0xFFBFE980)     = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/usr/lib/libsasl.so.1", "/usr/lib/libsasl.so.1", 1023) = 21
1065:   open("/usr/lib/libsasl.so.1", O_RDONLY)         = 4
1065:   stat64("/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libmd_psr.so.1", 0xFFBFE4C8) = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libmd_psr.so.1", "/platform/sun4v/lib/libmd_psr.so.1", 1023) = 34
1065:   open("/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libmd_psr.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 4
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/libmd.so.1", 0xFFBFE980)   Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/libnspr4.so", 0xFFBFE980)  = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/usr/lib/mps/libnspr4.so", "/usr/lib/mps/libnspr4.so", 1023) = 24
1065:   open("/usr/lib/mps/libnspr4.so", O_RDONLY)      = 4
1065:   stat64("/lib/libpthread.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0)      = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libpthread.so.1", "/lib/libpthread.so.1", 1023) = 20
1065:   open("/lib/libpthread.so.1", O_RDONLY)          = 4
1065:   stat64("/lib/librt.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0)           = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/librt.so.1", "/lib/librt.so.1", 1023) = 15
1065:   open("/lib/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY)               = 4
1065:   stat64("/lib/libdl.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0)           = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libdl.so.1", "/lib/libdl.so.1", 1023) = 15
1065:   open("/lib/libdl.so.1", O_RDONLY)               = 4
1065:   stat64("/lib/libaio.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0)          = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libaio.so.1", "/lib/libaio.so.1", 1023) = 16
1065:   open("/lib/libaio.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 4
1065:   sysinfo(SI_ISALIST, "sparcv9 sparcv8plus sparcv8 sparcv8-fsmuld sparcv7 sparc sparcv9+vis sparcv9+vis2 sparcv8plus+vis sparcv8plus+vis2", 257) = 115
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/cpu/sparcv9/libnspr_flt4.so", 0xFFBFE4C8) Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/cpu/sparcv8plus/libnspr_flt4.so", 0xFFBFE4C8) = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/usr/lib/mps/cpu/sparcv8plus/libnspr_flt4.so", "/usr/lib/mps/cpu/sparcv8plus/libnspr_flt4.so", 1023) = 44
1065:   open("/usr/lib/mps/cpu/sparcv8plus/libnspr_flt4.so", O_RDONLY) = 4
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/libplc4.so", 0xFFBFE980)   = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/usr/lib/mps/libplc4.so", "/usr/lib/mps/libplc4.so", 1023) = 23
1065:   open("/usr/lib/mps/libplc4.so", O_RDONLY)       = 4
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/libnss3.so", 0xFFBFE980)   = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/usr/lib/mps/libnss3.so", "/usr/lib/mps/libnss3.so", 1023) = 23
1065:   open("/usr/lib/mps/libnss3.so", O_RDONLY)       = 4
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/libnssutil3.so", 0xFFBFE8A0) = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/usr/lib/mps/libnssutil3.so", "/usr/lib/mps/libnssutil3.so", 1023) = 27
1065:   open("/usr/lib/mps/libnssutil3.so", O_RDONLY)   = 4
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/libplds4.so", 0xFFBFE8A0)  = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/usr/lib/mps/libplds4.so", "/usr/lib/mps/libplds4.so", 1023) = 24
1065:   open("/usr/lib/mps/libplds4.so", O_RDONLY)      = 4
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/secv1/libc.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0) Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/libssl3.so", 0xFFBFE980)   = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/usr/lib/mps/libssl3.so", "/usr/lib/mps/libssl3.so", 1023) = 23
1065:   open("/usr/lib/mps/libssl3.so", O_RDONLY)       = 4
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/libthread.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0) Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/secv1/libthread.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0) Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   stat64("/lib/libthread.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0)       = 0
1065:   resolvepath("/lib/libthread.so.1", "/lib/libthread.so.1", 1023) = 19
1065:   open("/lib/libthread.so.1", O_RDONLY)           = 4
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/librt.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0)   Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   stat64("/usr/lib/mps/secv1/librt.so.1", 0xFFBFE8A0) Err#2 ENOENT
1065:   write(2, " l d . s o . 1 :   p a s".., 130)     = 130
1065:   write(2, "\n", 1)                               = 1
1065:   lwp_self()                                      = 1
1064:   waitid(P_ALL, 0, 0xFFBFE980, WEXITED|WTRAPPED)  = 0
1064:   _exit(0)



# ldd /usr/sbin/passmgmt /usr/lib/passwdutil.so.1                 
/usr/sbin/passmgmt:
        libsecdb.so.1 =>         /lib/libsecdb.so.1
        passwdutil.so.1 =>       /usr/lib/passwdutil.so.1
        libc.so.1 =>     /lib/libc.so.1
        libnsl.so.1 =>   /lib/libnsl.so.1
        libcmd.so.1 =>   /lib/libcmd.so.1
        libsldap.so.1 =>         /usr/lib/libsldap.so.1
        libmp.so.2 =>    /lib/libmp.so.2
        libmd.so.1 =>    /lib/libmd.so.1
        libscf.so.1 =>   /lib/libscf.so.1
        libldap.so.5 =>  /usr/lib/libldap.so.5
        libdoor.so.1 =>  /lib/libdoor.so.1
        libuutil.so.1 =>         /lib/libuutil.so.1
        libgen.so.1 =>   /lib/libgen.so.1
        libsasl.so.1 =>  /usr/lib/libsasl.so.1
        libsocket.so.1 =>        /lib/libsocket.so.1
        libnspr4.so =>   /usr/lib/mps/libnspr4.so
        libplc4.so =>    /usr/lib/mps/libplc4.so
        libnss3.so =>    /usr/lib/mps/libnss3.so
        libssl3.so =>    /usr/lib/mps/libssl3.so
        libpthread.so.1 =>       /lib/libpthread.so.1
        librt.so.1 =>    /lib/librt.so.1
        libdl.so.1 =>    /lib/libdl.so.1
        libnssutil3.so =>        /usr/lib/mps/libnssutil3.so
        libplds4.so =>   /usr/lib/mps/libplds4.so
        libthread.so.1 =>        /lib/libthread.so.1
        libaio.so.1 =>   /lib/libaio.so.1
        libm.so.2 =>     /lib/libm.so.2
        /platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libc_psr.so.1
        /platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libmd_psr.so.1
        /usr/lib/mps/cpu/sparcv8plus/libnspr_flt4.so
/usr/lib/passwdutil.so.1:
        libcmd.so.1 =>   /lib/libcmd.so.1
        libsldap.so.1 =>         /usr/lib/libsldap.so.1
        libnsl.so.1 =>   /lib/libnsl.so.1
        libc.so.1 =>     /lib/libc.so.1
        libldap.so.5 =>  /usr/lib/libldap.so.5
        libscf.so.1 =>   /lib/libscf.so.1
        libdoor.so.1 =>  /lib/libdoor.so.1
        libmp.so.2 =>    /lib/libmp.so.2
        libmd.so.1 =>    /lib/libmd.so.1
        libsasl.so.1 =>  /usr/lib/libsasl.so.1
        libsocket.so.1 =>        /lib/libsocket.so.1
        libnspr4.so =>   /usr/lib/mps/libnspr4.so
        libplc4.so =>    /usr/lib/mps/libplc4.so
        libnss3.so =>    /usr/lib/mps/libnss3.so
        libssl3.so =>    /usr/lib/mps/libssl3.so
        libuutil.so.1 =>         /lib/libuutil.so.1
        libgen.so.1 =>   /lib/libgen.so.1
        libpthread.so.1 =>       /lib/libpthread.so.1
        librt.so.1 =>    /lib/librt.so.1
        libdl.so.1 =>    /lib/libdl.so.1
        libnssutil3.so =>        /usr/lib/mps/libnssutil3.so
        libplds4.so =>   /usr/lib/mps/libplds4.so
        libthread.so.1 =>        /lib/libthread.so.1
        libaio.so.1 =>   /lib/libaio.so.1
        libm.so.2 =>     /lib/libm.so.2
        /platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libc_psr.so.1
        /platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libmd_psr.so.1
        /usr/lib/mps/cpu/sparcv8plus/libnspr_flt4.so
# pkgchk SUNWtls1
WARNING: no pathnames were associated with <SUNWtls1>



# set|grep LD;crle;truss -w2 -ft open useradd -s /bin/bash -d /home/testuser -m testuser

Configuration file [version 4]: /var/ld/ld.config
  Platform:     32-bit MSB SPARC
  Default Library Path (ELF):   /lib:/usr/lib:/usr/sfw/lib
  Trusted Directories (ELF):    /lib/secure:/usr/lib/secure  (system default)

Command line:
  crle -c /var/ld/ld.config -l /lib:/usr/lib:/usr/sfw/lib

922:    open("/var/ld/ld.config", O_RDONLY)             = 3
922:    open("/lib/libsecdb.so.1", O_RDONLY)            = 3
922:    open("/usr/lib/libproject.so.1", O_RDONLY)      = 3
922:    open("/lib/libc.so.1", O_RDONLY)                = 3
922:    open("/lib/libnsl.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
922:    open("/lib/libcmd.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
922:    open("/lib/libproc.so.1", O_RDONLY)             = 3
922:    open("/lib/librtld_db.so.1", O_RDONLY)          = 3
922:    open("/lib/libelf.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
922:    open("/lib/libctf.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
922:    open("/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libc_psr.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
922:    open("/usr/sadm/defadduser", O_RDONLY)          = 3
922:    open("/proc/922/psinfo", O_RDONLY)              = 3
922:    open64("/var/run/name_service_door", O_RDONLY)  = 3
923:    open("/dev/null", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 1
923:    open("/dev/null", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 2
923:    open("/var/ld/ld.config", O_RDONLY)             = 3
923:    open("/lib/libsecdb.so.1", O_RDONLY)            = 3
923:    open("/usr/lib/passwdutil.so.1", O_RDONLY)      = 3
923:    open("/lib/libc.so.1", O_RDONLY)                = 3
923:    open("/lib/libnsl.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
923:    open("/lib/libcmd.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
923:    open("/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libc_psr.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
923:    open("/var/run/tzsync", O_RDONLY)               = 3
923:    open("/usr/share/lib/zoneinfo/US/Eastern", O_RDONLY) = 3
923:    open("/usr/lib/libsldap.so.1", O_RDONLY)        = 4
923:    open("/usr/lib/libldap.so.5", O_RDONLY)         = 4
923:    open("/lib/libscf.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 4
923:    open("/lib/libdoor.so.1", O_RDONLY)             = 4
923:    open("/lib/libuutil.so.1", O_RDONLY)            = 4
923:    open("/lib/libgen.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 4
923:    open("/lib/libsocket.so.1", O_RDONLY)           = 4
923:    open("/lib/libmp.so.2", O_RDONLY)               = 4
923:    open("/lib/libmd.so.1", O_RDONLY)               = 4
923:    open("/usr/lib/libsasl.so.1", O_RDONLY)         = 4
923:    open("/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libmd_psr.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 4
923:    open("/usr/lib/mps/libnspr4.so", O_RDONLY)      = 4
923:    open("/lib/libpthread.so.1", O_RDONLY)          = 4
923:    open("/lib/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY)               = 4
923:    open("/lib/libdl.so.1", O_RDONLY)               = 4
923:    open("/lib/libaio.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 4
923:    open("/usr/lib/mps/cpu/sparcv8plus/libnspr_flt4.so", O_RDONLY) = 4
923:    open("/usr/lib/mps/libplc4.so", O_RDONLY)       = 4
923:    open("/usr/lib/mps/libnss3.so", O_RDONLY)       = 4
923:    open("/usr/lib/mps/libnssutil3.so", O_RDONLY)   = 4
923:    open("/usr/lib/mps/libplds4.so", O_RDONLY)      = 4
923:    open("/usr/lib/mps/libssl3.so", O_RDONLY)       = 4
923:    open("/lib/libthread.so.1", O_RDONLY)           = 4
923:    write(2, 0xFF3FC74C, 130)                       = 130
923:       l d . s o . 1 :   p a s s m g m t :   f a t a l :   r e l o c a
923:       t i o n   e r r o r :   f i l e   / u s r / s b i n / p a s s m
923:       g m t :   s y m b o l   _ _ p w u _ l o c k i n g _ r e s t r i
923:       c t i v e :   r e f e r e n c e d   s y m b o l   n o t   f o u
923:       n d
923:    write(2, "\n", 1)                               = 1
925:    open("/var/ld/ld.config", O_RDONLY)             = 3
925:    open("/lib/libc.so.1", O_RDONLY)                = 3
925:    open("/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libc_psr.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
925:    open("/lib/libsec.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
925:    open("/lib/libavl.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
925:    open("/lib/libcmdutils.so.1", O_RDONLY)         = 3
925:    open64("/etc/skel/.profile", O_RDONLY)          = 4
925:    open64("/etc/skel/local.cshrc", O_RDONLY)       = 4
925:    open64("/etc/skel/local.login", O_RDONLY)       = 4
925:    open64("/etc/skel/local.profile", O_RDONLY)     = 4
927:    open("/var/ld/ld.config", O_RDONLY)             = 3
927:    open("/lib/libcmdutils.so.1", O_RDONLY)         = 3
927:    open("/lib/libc.so.1", O_RDONLY)                = 3
927:    open("/lib/libavl.so.1", O_RDONLY)              = 3
927:    open("/platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libc_psr.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
#
# passmgmt
ld.so.1: passmgmt: fatal: relocation error: file /usr/sbin/passmgmt: symbol __pwu_locking_restrictive: referenced symbol not found
Killed
#



# pkgchk SUNWcsl SUNWcslr SUNWdpl SUNWlibms SUNWlibmsr SUNWlibsasl SUNWpr SUNWtls
WARNING: no pathnames were associated with <SUNWdpl>



# ldd -dp /usr/bin/passmgmt
        libsecdb.so.1 =>         /lib/libsecdb.so.1
        passwdutil.so.1 =>       /usr/lib/passwdutil.so.1
        libc.so.1 =>     /lib/libc.so.1
        libnsl.so.1 =>   /lib/libnsl.so.1
        libcmd.so.1 =>   /lib/libcmd.so.1
        libsldap.so.1 =>         /usr/lib/libsldap.so.1
        libmp.so.2 =>    /lib/libmp.so.2
        libmd.so.1 =>    /lib/libmd.so.1
        libscf.so.1 =>   /lib/libscf.so.1
        libldap.so.5 =>  /usr/lib/libldap.so.5
        libdoor.so.1 =>  /lib/libdoor.so.1
        libuutil.so.1 =>         /lib/libuutil.so.1
        libgen.so.1 =>   /lib/libgen.so.1
        libsasl.so.1 =>  /usr/lib/libsasl.so.1
        libsocket.so.1 =>        /lib/libsocket.so.1
        libnspr4.so =>   /usr/lib/mps/libnspr4.so
        libplc4.so =>    /usr/lib/mps/libplc4.so
        libnss3.so =>    /usr/lib/mps/libnss3.so
        libssl3.so =>    /usr/lib/mps/libssl3.so
        libpthread.so.1 =>       /lib/libpthread.so.1
        librt.so.1 =>    /lib/librt.so.1
        libdl.so.1 =>    /lib/libdl.so.1
        libnssutil3.so =>        /usr/lib/mps/libnssutil3.so
        libplds4.so =>   /usr/lib/mps/libplds4.so
        libthread.so.1 =>        /lib/libthread.so.1
        libaio.so.1 =>   /lib/libaio.so.1
        libm.so.2 =>     /lib/libm.so.2
        /platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libc_psr.so.1
        /platform/SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200/lib/libmd_psr.so.1
        /usr/lib/mps/cpu/sparcv8plus/libnspr_flt4.so
```

---

Followup: A few weeks later, we ended up reinstalling the OS to resolve the issue.

Comment: you're not running the command as root. at least the root prompt normally is # instead of $. Also, when you do passwd you get permission denied.

Comment: Yes - I'm logged in as root. My PS1 is just set to "$ ". I do not receive a permission error when changing the password of a user that already exists.

Comment: I updated the prompt to "# " to prevent confusion. Thanks for the input.

Comment: pretty low odds stuff: try `lsattr /etc/passwd`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion jthill. I tried lsattr, but it appears that it is not installed on Solaris 10.

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to be observing is definitely not the expected behavior.

I suspect your `useradd` to be a wrapper to the real one dropping stderr and the command status.

This can be checked with this command:

```
type useradd
```

A common reason for useradd to fail with Solaris is the home automounter defeating the `-m` option.

This should work:

```
useradd -s /bin/bash -d /export/home/testuser -m testuser
```

PS: Using `#` for root's prompt is an established convention. Not following it, especially when posting, is definitely confusing.

---

Update:

There are a couple of thing to check:

1: it seems your ldap configuration is broken, for some reason, the loader no more looks in the standard directories to load libraries like libthread and librt. Try disabling ldap at least temporarily by removing out `ldap` from the password entry in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
passwd: files
```

then try again to create your user.

3: if `useradd` still fails, compare your pam configuration file (`/etc/pam.conf`) with the other servers one for any discrepancy.

4: If that fails too, I guess you installed something not compatible with the libraries and/or just miss Solaris patches.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, jiliagre. I updated the original post with the output of both commands. I also updated the PS1 from "$ " to "# " to follow convention and prevent confusion.

Comment: You should have tried the option I suggested `-b /export/home` and not `-d /home/testuser` but anyway, as the home directory are created, the problem is elsewhere. Please add the output of `df -k /home;ls -l@ /usr/sbin/useradd; pkgchk SUNWcsu; grep passwd: /etc/nsswitch.conf` to your question.

Comment: Thanks jilliagre. I had used -d instead because useradd gave me a syntax error with the -b option. I also don't have a /export directory on this box.

I added the output of those commands to the question.

Comment: Sorry, the `-b` isn't fully implemented in Solaris 10, would have work in Solaris 11. Please post this command output: `userdel testuser;truss -t!memcntl,getuid,door_call,door_info,close,mmap,brk,munmap,lwp_sigmask,sigaction,llseek -f useradd -m -d /tmp/testuser testuser`

Comment: We are getting closer, please run `ldd /usr/sbin/passmgmt /usr/lib/passwdutil.so.1, pkgchk SUNWtls1`.

Comment: Ok- I added the output to the post.

Comment: answer updated.

Comment: Hey jlliagre, I removed ldap from nsswitch.conf, but no luck. I didn't see anything unusual in pam.conf, but I did try restoring it to the original configuration. No luck. I'm going to try to patch this box and if that doesn't work, I will reinstall the OS. Thanks for your assistance. At least I learned a few things while trying to figure this out.

Comment: Can you run `set|grep LD;crle;truss -w2 -ft open useradd -s /bin/bash -d /home/testuser -m testuser` ?

Comment: Yes, I will update my post with the output. It looks like you're on to something here.

Comment: `pkgchk SUNWcsl SUNWcslr SUNWdpl SUNWlibms SUNWlibmsr SUNWlibsasl SUNWpr SUNWtls` ?

Comment: Updated post with output

Comment: `ldd -dp /usr/bin/passmgmt` ?

Comment: Updated post with output

Comment: Are you up to date with Solaris patches ?